# Error in saving GridSearchCV best estimator model and converting it to TFLite format

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, scikit-learn, gridsearchcv

I am saving the best model from GridSearchCV of my CNN model and there is an error occuring which hinders me from converting it into a TFLite file and apply quantization.

Here is my code:

```
def create_model(learning_rate):
    mobilenet = MobileNet(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=input_shape)

    for layer in mobilenet.layers:
      layer.trainable = False

    x = Flatten()(mobilenet.output)
    output = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(x)
    model = Model(inputs=mobilenet.input, outputs=output)

    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate)
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

model = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=1)

grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid, scoring=scoring, refit='f1_score', verbose=2, cv=2)

grid_result = grid_search.fit(X_subset, y_subset)

best_model = grid_search.best_estimator_
```

Now, in the code below, I can't save then load the models when using either joblib or pickle as the following error occurs.

```
import pickle

with open('filename.pkl', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(best_model, f)

with open('filename.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    pickled_model = pickle.load(f)
```

Error:

```
TypeError: Error when deserializing class 'ReLU' using config={'name': 'conv1_relu', 'trainable': False, 'dtype': 'float32', 'max_value': {'class_name': '__numpy__', 'config': {'value': 6.0, 'dtype': 'float32'}}, 'negative_slope': {'class_name': '__numpy__', 'config': {'value': 0.0, 'dtype': 'float32'}}, 'threshold': {'class_name': '__numpy__', 'config': {'value': 0.0, 'dtype': 'float32'}}}.

Exception encountered: '<' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'float'
```